# Service or services?

Tags: grammar

I've read many articles that use the term 'emergency services ' and ' location services' .

Why not service instead? Why must it be plural? Thank you

Comment: *Why **must** it be plural?* Who said it must? If it is plural then presumably there is more than one service.

Answer (score 1):

*Emergency services*:

Refers to the collection of emergency services. E.g.:

- Fire service
- Police service
- Ambulance service

The singular form, *emergency service* refers to any singular emergency service (e.g., fire service).

Similarly there are a set of *location services*:

e.g. *find my phone*, *location based alerts*, *cell network search* etc. (as the photo on [Apples support site](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203033) demonstrates, for instance)

[image: Apple Location Services]

Location services refers to all of them, location service refers to any one of the singular services.

Comment: You're welcome, anytime :)

Answer (score 1):

The plural form 'services' is used mainly because most institutions typically provide not just one service, but **a variety or range of services**.

In fact, when a single or predominant service is provided, the singular form 'service' is often used instead of 'services' as in **laundry service**,  **answering service** and **courier service**.